# Fetch value from Local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage, google-tag-manager

I have hardly any coding experience but I work with web analytics and tracking in Google Tag Manager.

I want to fetch the value of a local storage keyname. I have tried both functions below with custom javascript (Custom javascript variable in GTM) but the variable still gets undefined.
Would it be possible to fetch the value of Keyname "SeersCMPConsent" and if so, what code could be used?

```
function() {
  var keyValue = sessionStorage.getItem('SeersCMPConsent');
  return keyValue;
}
```

```
function() {
  var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('SeersCMPConsent'));
  return obj.value;
}
```

Local storage value
[image: Local storage value]

Comment: Reading between the lines here: that value has been written into the storage by GTM and you are trying to read it as not-GTM (or vice versa, _something_ put the value there and your custom GTM script tries to read it)?

Comment: Your second script should work. Can you share the screenshot about when does it shows undefined in your GTM preview?

Answer (score -1):

You should try this to reach you desired output.

```
function getDataFromLocalStorage() {
    var obj = localStorage.getItem("SeersCMPConsent");
    return JSON.parse(obj)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Remove the JSON.parse(); and just put it like this.

```
let storage = localStorage.getItem('SeersCMPConsent');

console.log(storage.value);
```

It will work.
Vote-up if it work, so I will know if it  did.